# Spell and Grammar checking engine with RESTful API

Tags: spell-checker, grammar

If I think of automated writing support service, the following examples come to my mind:

- Microsoft Word with some proprietary engine
- Open Source engine from Open Office, [Hunspell](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell)
- Commerical online service with a free Firefox plugin Grammarly

Is there a solution with a RESTful API?

Comment: programmableweb lists 18 results for "grammar" though a quick check shows they aren't all halfway close to what you want, the others may deserve looking at as well.  https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?keyword=grammar

Answer (score 3):

As I typed in this question, many thoughts followed by more googling came to my mind, and after a half an hour or so I think I have found it.

http://wiki.languagetool.org/public-http-api

Side note: also Language Tool offers a free Firefox plugin.

Still, maybe this insight could help someone to save time, therefore hope it's okay to retain this question and answer.

Comment: You are encouraged to accept your own answer, because doing so will help others in future. Thanks for that URL, btw :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a free tool, the easiest grammar checking API that I found with a RESTful API is Grammar Bot:

https://www.grammarbot.io/

It's under active development, which most of the free grammar checkers are not.