# Is there an API (or URL) to directly or indirectly check Google's spell correct?

Tags: spell-checker, google

I see [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52649/spell-and-grammar-checking-engine-with-restful-api) but I am going to make mine a little different.

I really like the quality of Google Docs spell check.  I have a program which outputs near misses and I test some of these near misses and Google Docs beats everything I have seen hands down.

Therefore, within everything Google has to offer, paid or free-tier, is there any (legitimate) way to access Google's spelling capabilities?  If I could download their dictionary, I still don't think is good enough, because it would not contain the context portion.

Comment: Take a look at this question, it is similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846563/google-docs-spell-checker-api-is-it-available

Answer (score 0):

I have seen [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com), however that does not give me enough hits/month, therefore it is not useable for me.  However, it does seem to do what I say, and returns back the correction with just a few lines of code (and supplying the private api key you have to sign up for).